# Change the CSS of Checkbox inside the script template

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I am using list,Inside i have checkbox,where it is taking default CSS of checkbox,how i can change the CSS style of checkbox below is my code.I need to change the css of checkbox

```
  <div id="DepartmentList">
          <ul  data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-template="script-id" data-source="listData"></ul>
          <script id="script-id" type="text/x-kendo-template">
              <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="#: department#" class="checkclass" onchange="handleDepartmentChange(this);" />
                  <h3 class="checkclass">#: department#</h3>

              </div>
          </script>
      </div>
```

Comment: use important! on the styles you want to use as well to force it to use those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 input[type="checkbox"].checkclass {
  //your CSS
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the checkbox with your css.

Like this in your css:

```
.checkbox_style{
     width:47px; //Example 
}
```

And your checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="#: department#" class="checkclass checkbox_style" onchange="handleDepartmentChange(this);" />
```